# Looking to catch a ride from Idaho falls to Sacramento, can anyone help get me going?

Tags: hitchhiking

Looking to catch a ride from Idaho falls to Sacramento, can anyone help get me going? I have 1 suitcase and 1 backpack.

Comment: We can help you find places to find rides, we do not help in finding rides, we are not that kind of site.

Answer (score 4):

That's 750 miles between two "minor" cities. You can try carpooling sites like https://www.blablacar.co.uk/ https://www.carpoolworld.com/ . BlaBla car works well in Europe between major cities but it's not as established in the US.

Your chances of finding some that will drive this exact route are not great. You may have to break it up in multiple segments. You can also check https://www.rome2rio.com/ for alternatives.

Stay Safe !